# Invisible text on requestPermissions buttons

Tags: android

I need to request permission to access photos, media and files on the users device so request as much using:

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, requestCode)`

The actual request works fine however the "CANCEL" and "OK" buttons that appear on the dialog are illegible:
[image]

Note there are "CANCEL" and "OK" buttons in the bottom right corner (visible in LayoutInspector) however they have white text. The buttons also "splash" and respond to click/taps as expected, it's just impossible for the user to see them before tapping.

There is no doubt some theme property I've overwritten or something which is causing the textColor to be #FFFFFF but I can't for the life of me work out what it is. Any idea what I need to set to bring the text back to being a reasonable colour?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide your styles.xml file?

Comment: That's a fair request however the entire styles system in this project is extremely long and convoluted and unfortunately it's not really feasible to provide. Are there any properties in particular I can supply to help?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found a workaround.

Turns out I was constructing the dialog using:
`new AlertDialog.Builder(context, myTheme);`

With the parent of `myTheme` being `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert`.

It seems deriving "myTheme" from `Theme.MaterialComponents...` instead of `Theme.AppCompat...` causes the buttons to be rendered in purple which, although unexpected, is at lease visible: ;)

Note I now have a follow up question here:
['Material' vs 'MaterialComponents'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66129730/materil-vs-materialcomponents)