# 'Material' vs 'MaterialComponents'

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-dialog, material-components-android

What is the difference between `Theme.Material...` and `Theme.MaterialComponents...`?

I am creating an alert dialogue and when I create it using:

`new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);`

I get "colorAccent" coloured text on the buttons.

However when I create the dialog using:

`return new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.myTheme);`

with:
`<style name="myTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert"/>`

I seem to get purple coloured text. What is the difference between these?

And finally if I were to derive "myTheme" from `Theme.AppCompat...` (instead of `Theme.MaterialComponent...`) I get white text. What is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Theme.Material` is provided by Android starting with API 21.
The `Theme.MaterialComponents` is provided by the Material Components library.
They are completely different.

If you want to use the Material Components Library the best way is to use the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`.

```
return new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context, R.style.myTheme);
```

and inherit the theme overlay from:

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
```

Here you can check all the [default attributes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md#anatomy-and-key-properties) applied to the theme.